# In python, how to remove blank spaces from a line in a file

Tags: python

I have a file below

```sh
~$ cat test_alerts
"test-everything"|["messages,kubelet.service"]|[{"triggerinterval": "12h", "triggerlimit": 1, "integration": "email", "immediate": false, "terminal": true, "operator": "presence", "emails": ["fun@us.com"]}]|"3fddf26cb4"
```

I want to remove spaces after : & , in the above file, tried with below code, not seems to be working

```py
import os

filepath = os.path.expanduser('~')
cleanedLine = []

with open('test_alerts', "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        cleanedLine = line.strip()
        if cleanedLine: # is not empty
            print(cleanedLine)
```

Comment: is that a `test_alerts` is a  `.txt` file? If yes then you should use `for line in f.readlines()` instead of `for line in f`

Answer (score 0):

`str.strip()` only removes blank spaces (and a couple of other stuff) at the beginning and end of a string. What you are looking for is [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

The rest of your code seems a bit odd as well. The if-condition would only be applied to the last `cleanedLine` in the file since it's outside the for-loop. Further, the print-statement is wrongly indented since it is on the same level as the if-condition.  And lastly, you first define `cleanedLine` as a list using `cleanedLine = []` while you later turn it into a string. Depending on what you are trying to achieve you would either use `cleanedLine.append(line.strip())` to fill the list or would define `cleanedLine = None` or `cleanedLine = ''` to not switch types.

Comment: "you first define `cleanedLine` as a dict using `cleanedLine = []`" - I think you mean't a list ? because that is what `[]` is - a list, not a dict. And a dict doesn't have an `.append` method, either …